# How to send iOS push notifications through AWS Pinpoint and firebase?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, aws-pinpoint

I would like to know how to send iOS push notifications throught AWS Pinpoint with the `GCMMessage` channel.
Can anyone provide a working json payload that gets sent through FCM to an iOS device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the same payload for Android is used with iOS, but for sending data messages I had to add the property `"content_available": "1"`

```
payload = {
                "notification": {
                    "title": "title",
                    "body": "body",
                    "sound": "default",
                    "badge":"1"
                },
                "content_available": "1",
                "data": {
                    "key_1": "some value",
                    "key_2": "some value"
                }
            }
```